# Use The Code Only One Time In my asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class there is a code and this class is execute every time when website start.

I want to use the class run only single time when my website is start.

What can I do...?

Answer (score 5):

You may put the code in `Application_Start` event in `global.asax`. In your `global.asax` file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        //Yourclass.YourMethod();

    }
```

That code will execute only once at the application startup.

You may want to see: [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)